# How can I change on to off on this Switch case?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a list of switches (iOS) with "value" values from a DB, but I don't know how change this value when I press the switch. (Ex. If I have one switch with "value" equal to "false", I want the "value" to change to "true" when I press the switch).

Thank you!!!

```js
import { Switch } from 'react-native';

renderServicesContent = section => {
    let taskrendered = [];
    let checked      = false;

    updateTasks    = this.state.updateTaks;
    deleteTaskFunc = this.state.deleteTaskFunc;

    section.default_tasks.map(function(elemen, index) {
        concatService = elemen.description;

        if (elemen.verified == 1 || elemen.verified == 2) {
            checked = true;
        } else {
            checked = false;
        }

        let disabledCheck = false;
        if (section.status == "4") {
            disabledCheck = true;
        } else {
            disabledCheck = false;
        }

        taskrendered.push(
            <ListItem>
                <Switch
                    style={{
                        flex: 1, 
                        padding: 10, 
                        marginRight: normalize(8)
                    }}
                    onValueChange={() => this.updateTasks(elemen)}
                    value={checked}
                />
                <Text 
                    style={{
                        marginLeft: normalize(28), 
                        marginRight: normalize(16)
                    }
                >
                    {concatService}
                </Text>
            </ListItem>
        );
    });
    
    return (
        <View>
            {taskrendered}
        </View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
state={
    checked:[]
}
```

The toggle function you are using doesn't toggle the checked items as you are using push change your code something like below :

```
import { Switch } from 'react-native';

renderServicesContent = section => {
    let taskrendered = [];
    let checked = false;

    updateTasks = this.state.updateTaks;
    deleteTaskFunc = this.state.deleteTaskFunc;

    for (var i = 0; i < section.default_tasks.length; i++) {
        if (section.default_tasks[i].verified == 1 || section.default_tasks[i].verifie == 2) {
            this.state.checked[i] = true;
        } else {
            this.state.checked[i] = false;
        }
    }

    // section.default_tasks.map(function(elemen, index) {
    //     concatService = elemen.description;

    //     if (elemen.verified == 1 || elemen.verified == 2) {
    //         this.state.checked[i] = true;
    //     } else {
    //         this.state.checked[i] = false;
    //     }

    //     let disabledCheck = false;
    //     if (section.status == "4") {
    //         disabledCheck = true;
    //     } else {
    //         disabledCheck = false;
    //     }

    //     taskrendered.push(
    //         <ListItem>
    //             <Switch
    //                 style={{
    //                     flex: 1, 
    //                     padding: 10, 
    //                     marginRight: normalize(8)
    //                 }}
    //                 onValueChange={() => this.updateTasks(elemen)}
    //                 value={checked}
    //             />
    //             <Text>
    //                 {concatService}
    //             </Text>
    //         </ListItem>
    //     );
    // });

    return (
        <View>
            {
                section.default_tasks.map((item, key) => {
                    return (
                        <ListItem>
                            <Switch
                                style={{
                                    flex: 1,
                                    padding: 10,
                                }}
                                onValueChange={(value) => {
                                    this.state.checked[key] = value;
                                    this.setState({
                                        checked: this.state.checked
                                    })

                                }}
                                value={this.state.checked[key]}
                            />
                            <Text

                            >
                                {item.description}
                            </Text>
                        </ListItem>
                    )
                })
            }
        </View>
    );
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: All switches will have the same value now. I think that's not what the author wants.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but...
Sorry but it doesn't work, 'cause I need to use "checked" variable to fill all the switches states. (Ex. 1st = false, 2nd = true, 3rd = false, 4th = false). So, I want to change the 2nd and 3rd switch to the opposite value (2nd = false and 3rd = true).

If I use this.state.checked[index] = false, checked values are never used.... I need a function or fill the onChangeValue={} to change the first "checked" value to "!checked"

Comment: In the initial state itself you need to have 2  to be true and 3 to be false and when you change 2 check box 3 also need to change is it right or just you need to toggles the switches

Comment: I had made some changes in my answer you should not use push here, and change the conditions like you required in initial condition.